# One Function Expanding into Another Function?

Tags: sequences-and-series, functions, vector-spaces, hilbert-spaces, fourier-series

How can one expand the function $f_1(x) = x$ on $(−π, π)$in terms of the functions $\cos nx, n = 0, 1, 2, ...$ and $\sin nx, n = 1, 2, ...,$ I read the below function -
$$f_2(x) = a_0 + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(a_n \cos nx + b_n \sin nx)$$

is the expansion of the $f_1$, how is that?

**Main Question:**

Is $f_1$ equivalent to $f_2$ in some way? If so, plz provide a detail proof which is easily comprehensible.

I have attached the excerpt below -

[image]

Comment: This is a standard application of [Fourier series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_series). And yes, $f_1$ and $f_2$ are equivalent in the sense that $f_1(x)=f_2(x)$ for all $x\in(-\pi,\pi)$. For any $x$ in this interval, the Fourier series will converge to $f(x)$.

Comment: @M.Nestor could u plz post a detail comprehensible for beginner answer regarding $f_1=f_2$ that shows the convergence or at least provide a link to similar problem's solution? Thanks.

Comment: @Carlo because could not understand in this post

Answer (score 3):

As already mentioned in the comments, this is known as a Fourier series. The set of square-integrable functions forms an infinite dimensional vector space called $L^2$-space:

$$L^2[-\pi, +\pi] =\bigg\{f\colon[-\pi, +\pi]\to\mathbb R \biggm\vert \int\limits_{-\pi}^{+\pi} \!\! |f(x)|^2 dx < \infty \bigg\}$$

In fact, it is even a Hilbert space with the inner product

$$ \langle f, g\rangle_{L^2[-\pi, +\pi]} = \int\limits_{-\pi}^{+\pi} \!\!f(x)g(x) d x$$

which induces the norm $\|f\|_{L^2[-\pi, +\pi]}^2 = \langle f, f\rangle_{L^2[-\pi, +\pi]}$.  The above is not 100% correct, there is a technicality involved that needs to be accounted for: one needs to "mod out" functions that are equal w.r.t. the $L^2$-norm. For example, consider the functions $f(x) = 0$ and $g(x) = \begin{cases}1:x=0\\0:x\neq 0\end{cases}$. Here $\|f-g\|=0$, since the functions only differ on a set of measure zero. However, for $L^2$ to be a proper normed vector-space, we need $\|h\|=0 \iff h=0$. Therefore, we need to identify functions with each other whenever their $L^2$ distance is zero. (Alternatively, one can use the completion of the space of square integrable **continuous** functions)

With this in mind, we can do Linear Algebra in $L^2$, in particular we can construct orthogonal basis (which are sometimes called [Schauder basis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schauder_basis) in the case of infinite dimensional vector spaces) and express functions in terms of these bases. And this is exactly what the Fourier Series does! The functions $f_1$ and $f_2$ are then equivalent in the $L^2$ sense:

$$ \lim_{N\to\infty}\bigg\|f_1(x) - \sum_{n=1}^N \big(a_n \cos(nx) + b_n\sin(nx)\big)\bigg\| = 0$$

Comment: [1]. You wrote "express functions in terms of these bases" ... does it mean for any given basis set, we can rewrite a function?

[2].  "this is exactly what the Fourier Series does!".... So you mean if one has a basis set, then any function can be represented in terms of that basis set using Fourier Series, i.e. Fourier Series Theory allows one function to be rewritten in another using a given basis set... if that is true, could you plz provide link of a lecture document/book chapter available online and suitable for beginner for me?

Comment: [3]. I want to the proof of below - 

$$ \lim_{N\to\infty}\bigg\|f_1(x) - \sum_{n=1}^N \big(a_n \cos(nx) + b_n\sin(nx)\big)\bigg\| = 0$$

Comment: @Andrew Are you sure? The proof is extremely difficult. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_Fourier_series) for some details.

Answer (score 2):

@Hyperplane 's answer already does a great job of explaining what this is all about, but just in case you're not comfortable with all of the "infinite dimensional Hilbert space" and "scalar product" stuff, I'll relate it to something a bit more concrete. Let's talk about vectors in the Hilbert space $\mathbb{R}^3$. Suppose we have a vector $\mathbf{v}$ with $x$ component $a$, $y$ component $b$, and $z$ component $c$. Now, we could express this as $\mathbf{v}=(a,b,c)$, but there is a potentially more informative way of expressing it, which we write as $$\mathbf{v}=a\hat{\mathbf{i}}+b\hat{\mathbf{j}}+c\hat{\mathbf{k}}$$
This might seem really basic, but what *exactly* is going on here? This is surprisingly deep: I've chosen a *basis* for the vector space $\mathbb{R}^3$ which I can use to express any vector as a sum of the *basis vectors*.

But we can express $\mathbf{v}$ in yet another way still! Notice that $\mathbf{v}\boldsymbol{\cdot}\hat{\mathbf{i}}=a$, $\mathbf{v}\boldsymbol{\cdot}\hat{\mathbf{j}}=b$, and $\mathbf{v}\boldsymbol{\cdot}\hat{\mathbf{k}}=c$. So we can write $\mathbf{v}$ as $(\mathbf{v}\boldsymbol{\cdot}\hat{\mathbf{i}},\mathbf{v}\boldsymbol{\cdot}\hat{\mathbf{j}},\mathbf{v}\boldsymbol{\cdot}\hat{\mathbf{k}})$. Why does this work? Well, if we want to know what the $x$ component of $\mathbf{v}$ is, we would measure how much it points in the $x$ direction, or how *similar* $\mathbf{v}$ is to the $x$ unit vector, $\hat{\mathbf{i}}$, and the tool we use to measure this is known as the dot product.

It's also easy to see how we can extend this to any finite number of dimensions. If $\mathbf{v}=(a_1,...,a_n)$ we can also express it as
$$\mathbf{v}=\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_i\hat{\mathbf{e}_i}=((\mathbf{v}\boldsymbol{\cdot}\hat{\mathbf{e}_1}),...,(\mathbf{v}\boldsymbol{\cdot}\hat{\mathbf{e}_n}))=\sum_{i=1}^{n}(\mathbf{v}\boldsymbol{\cdot}\hat{\mathbf{e}_i})\hat{\mathbf{e}_i}$$
Or, with some care, to an infinite number of dimensions. If $\mathbf{v}=(a_1,a_2,...)$
$$\mathbf{v}=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}a_i\hat{\mathbf{e}_i}=((\mathbf{v}\boldsymbol{\cdot}\hat{\mathbf{e}_1}),(\mathbf{v}\boldsymbol{\cdot}\hat{\mathbf{e}_2}),...)=\sum_{i=1}^\infty (\mathbf{v}\boldsymbol{\cdot}\hat{\mathbf{e}_i})\hat{\mathbf{e}_i}$$
Provided $\mathbf{v}$ is of finite size, i.e $\Vert\mathbf{v}\Vert^2=\mathbf{v}\boldsymbol{\cdot}\mathbf{v}=\sum_{i=1}^\infty {a_i}^2$ is finite.

So how can we use these ideas when talking about the Hilbert space of continuous, square integrable functions, also known as $L^2$ functions on the interval $[-\pi,\pi]$? Here, instead of a vector $\mathbf{v}$, we have an $L^2$ function $f$. Instead of the dot product $\_\boldsymbol{\cdot}\_$, we have the scalar or inner product $\langle\_,\_\rangle$, defined as
$$\langle f,g \rangle=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(x)g(x)\mathrm{d}x$$
As mentioned by @Hyperplane , in order for us to be able to deal with the function $f$ we need to check that
$$\langle f,f\rangle =\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi f(x)^2 \mathrm{d}x$$
Is finite.

Finally, instead of the basis vectors $\hat{\mathbf{e}_1},\hat{\mathbf{e}_2},\hat{\mathbf{e}_3},...$ we have the following basis **functions**: The cosine functions $\cos(x)$, $\cos(2x),...$ and the sine functions $\sin(x)$, $\sin(2x)...$ , and finally the constant function $1$. Therefore, we can represent $f$ as a sum of all of these basis functions. And in order to work out the coefficients in the sum, we use the inner product we mentioned before-we measure *how similar* $f$ is to the constant function and to the cosine and sine functions mentioned. Thus, we can write
$$f(x)=\langle f(x),1\rangle +2\sum_{n=1}^\infty \bigg[ \left\langle f(x),\cos(nx)\right\rangle \cos(nx)\bigg]+2\sum_{n=1}^\infty \bigg[ \left\langle f(x),\sin(nx)\right\rangle \sin(nx)\bigg]$$
Well, the $2$s in front of the sums are a little difficult to explain, but I hope you get the idea. The coefficients $2\left\langle f,\cos(nx)\right\rangle$ and $2\left\langle f,\sin(nx)\right\rangle$ are often given the names $a_n$ and $b_n$, and $\langle f,1\rangle$ is often given the name $\frac{a_0}{2}$, therefore we can write
$$f(x)=\frac{a_0}{2}+\sum_{n=1}^\infty \bigg[a_n\cos(nx)+b_n\sin(nx)\bigg].$$

**EDIT:**
I just wanted to add to my answer to make it somewhat more complete. The reason that there is a 2 in front of the inner product sums of sine and cosine is because while $\sin(nx)$ and $\cos(nx)$ are indeed a basis of $L^2$ functions on $[-\pi,\pi]$, they are not an *orthonormal basis*, that is
$$\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi\sin^2(nx)\mathrm{d}x=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi\cos^2(nx)\mathrm{d}x=\frac{1}{2}\neq 1$$
So we should really be using the functions $2\sin(nx),2\cos(nx)$. So we can write
$$a_n=\langle f(x),2\cos(nx)\rangle=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi f(x)\cdot2\cos(nx)\mathrm{d}x=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi f(x)\cos(nx)\mathrm{d}x$$
And similarly for $b_n$. We then write $\frac{a_0}{2}$ to stay consistent with the definition of $a_n$ above. Notice
$$a_0=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi f(x)\cos(0\cdot x)\mathrm{d}x=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi f(x)\mathrm{d}x$$
However, the coefficient in front of the constant function $1$ should be equal to
$$\langle f(x),1\rangle=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi f(x)\mathrm{d}x=\frac{a_0}{2}$$

Comment: The line "Therefore, we can represent $f $as a sum of all of these basis functions. " is not clear.. and the remaining part .... how can we  reason.

Comment: @Andrew Well, it assumes that $1, \sin(nx) \cos(nx)$ are a proper basis of $L^2$ functions on $-\pi,\pi$. Proving this is... Difficult. You might want to check want to check out [this page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_Fourier_series). The point of this post was to show the connection between the functional "vectors" involved in Fourier Series and the more typical vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$. The point is we can view sines and cosines as building blocks which we can add up to make any periodic function.

Comment: Would u plz name the topics in an orders that I need to learn to understand what I asked in my previous comment if possible advise book chapter or lecture notes available online, suitable for beginners like me?

Comment: @Andrew You should learn differential and integral calculus as well as linear algebra, all of which are available from Khan Academy. And, for a better conceptual understanding of both, 3Blue1Brown has video series on the "essence of calculus" and "essence of linear algebra" that are definitely worth a watch.

Comment: I am well aware of all your mentioned topics, anything else? I meant to the specific problem I mentioned in the first comment

Comment: @Andrew It's a direct application of linear algebra to integral calculus... Perhaps learn about Hilbert spaces and Fourier analysis as well?

Comment: Actually the source of problem is Hilbert Space, see : https://www.math.usm.edu/lambers/mat415/lecture1.pdf   .... but it does not address Fourier analysis ..

Comment: @Andrew Those notes do a good job of covering the conceptual groundwork. Fourier Series (and Fourier transforms) are *indispensable* when studying ODEs (especially those without closed form solutions) so you'll need to get to grips with this topic. But proofs that the series mentioned above converges to $f$ are **very** difficult, so in my modest opinion I would advise you to take it pretty much at face-value and then study the proof when you're further along in your mathematical journey.

Comment: @Andrew I've added some explanation as to why the mysterious "$2$" factors appear.

Comment: No, definitely $\langle f(x),1\rangle$. We want to find what the coefficient in front of the constant function $1$ should be in the Fourier series representation of $f$, i.e, the constant factor outside the infinite sums involving sines and cosines and stuff. We know that this should be equal to $\langle f(x),1\rangle$, as this is a measure of how similar $f$ is to $1$. But, when you plug in $n=0$ into the formula for $a_n$, you actually find that $\langle f(x),1\rangle=\frac{a_0}{2}.$

Comment: Oh yes I got, just after i posted the comment... sorry.. shouldn't have disturbed u over this trivial issue  :)  but, I can't wrap around my head how one can write $f_1=f_2$.....

Comment: @Andrew We do it the same way that we break up vectors into their components. The two tricky parts are that A: the number of "dimensions" is infinite, and B: actually *proving* that the above sums converge to $f$ as long as it is piecewise continuous with only finitely or countably infinitely many discontinuities is difficult. The main thing you need to know is that the $\langle,\rangle$ is basically the "dot product" when talking about $L^2$ functions and $1,\cos(nx),\sin(nx)$ are an orthogonal basis in the same way that $\hat{\mathbf{e}_1},...,\hat{\mathbf{e}_n}$ are in $\mathbb{R}^n$.