# How to derive $\frac1\pi \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(t)\sin nt \;\mathrm{d}t$ from $\frac{\langle\sin nx|f\rangle}{\langle \sin nx|\sin nx\rangle}$?

Tags: integration, functions, vector-spaces, hilbert-spaces

How to get $$\frac{\langle\sin nx|f\rangle}{\langle \sin nx|\sin nx\rangle}=\frac1\pi \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(t)\sin nt \;\mathrm{d}t?$$
To be specific, $\langle \sin nx|\sin nx\rangle$ becomes $\frac1\pi?$

I have attached the excerpt below -

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you meant the following:$$\pi\stackrel{?}{=}\langle\sin nx | \sin nx \rangle:=\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} (\sin nx)^*\cdot\sin nx\:dx=\int_{-\pi}^\pi\sin^2 nx\:dx$$
and indeed, the integral does equal $\pi$ (can be easily seen by using $\cos2nx=1-2\sin^2 nx$).

EDIT (OPs request) We have to evaluate
$$ \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \sin^2 nx\:dx=\frac{1}{2}\int_{-\pi}^\pi(1-\cos 2nx)\:dx=\frac{1}{2}\left.\left(x-\frac{\sin 2nx}{2n}\right)\right|_{-\pi}^{\pi}=\pi$$

Comment: I hope it is clear now.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3745025/one-function-expanding-into-another-function