# Proving: $x = a_0 + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(a_n \cos nx + b_n \sin nx)$

Tags: analysis, vector-spaces, fourier-analysis, hilbert-spaces, fourier-series

How can one expand the function $f_1(x) = x$ on $(−π, π)$in terms of the functions $\cos nx, n = 0, 1, 2, ...$ and $\sin nx, n = 1, 2, ...,$ in a way so that
$$f_2(x) = a_0 + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(a_n \cos nx + b_n \sin nx)$$

is the expansion of the $f_1$, how is that?

I have asked [a question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3745025/one-function-expanding-into-another-function) related to the same issue but didn't get full answer, I have been told that this is a standard application of Fourier series, $f_1$ and $f_2$ are equivalent in the sense that $f_1(x)=f_2(x)$ for all $x∈(−π,π)$. For any $x$ in this interval, the Fourier series will converge to $f(x)$, but **I didn't get any rigorous proof  with elaborate explanation.**

So, plz provide rigorous proof of $f_1=f_2$ with elaborate explanation as I am new to the subject. Thanks You.

I have attached the excerpt below -

[image]

Comment: What is your question exactly ? You ask "how is that ?", but what do you call *that* ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust  I read this: https://www.math.usm.edu/math/lambers/mat415/lecture1.pdf   .. I guess I do understand, but there might be some kind of incompleteness, by "that" I mean, How the equation $f_1=f_2$ holds for a certain interval. No it didn't Imentioned that in my post.

Comment: @YvesDaoust  u said, (you didn't answer my first question), but I did, I said: "I read this: math.usm.edu/math/lambers/mat415/lecture1.pdf .. I guess I do understand, but there might be some kind of incompleteness"..... uwrote "yo obtain an integral expression for these." ... could u plz post an elaborate answer explaining the whole process?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [One Function Expanding into Another Function?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3745025/one-function-expanding-into-another-function)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a lot of Pointwise and other types of Fourier series  [convergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_Fourier_series). I bring, for example, one of the first sufficient condition proved by Dirichlet:

If function with period $2\pi$ is piecewise monotonic in segment $[-\pi, \pi]$ and has only finite points of discontinuity, then its Fourier series converged to $f(x_0)$ for each $x_0$ point of continuity, and to $\frac{f(x_0+0)+f(x_0-0)}{2}$ in points of discontinuity.

So, we can consider $f(x)=x$ function on $[-\pi, \pi]$ and use this theorem.

For odd function $\int\limits_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(x)dx=0$ and so $\int\limits_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(x) \cos nxdx=a_n \pi=0$, so in such cases we have
$$f(x) \sim \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}b_n \sin nx$$

Comment: Why $a_n=0$ because of $f$ is an odd function?  as I see $\langle\cos nx | \cos nx \rangle =\pi$.. so what is the differences?

Comment: Added to answer.

Comment: Then $f(x) \sin(nx)$ is also odd and the related integration should also be 0, why that is not?

Comment: When $f(x)$ is odd, then $f(x) \sin nx$ is even and $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} = 2 \int_{0}^{\pi}$

Comment: okay, could u point out where can I find proof of the following statement written in the attached image: $\;$" The functions $\cos (nx), n = 0, 1, 2, \cdots$ and $\sin (nx), n = 1, 2, \cdots $ which are known
to be orthogonal with respect to the standard scalar product on $(−\pi, \pi)$."

Comment: Product of $\sin nx$ and $\cos nx$ is odd, therefore scalar product is $0$ - we discussed this above. Or you mean something else?

Comment: Yes, but why it is mentioned in the way I have quoted, i mean we are doing scalar product of $f$ and $\sin nx$, scalar product of $f$ and $cos nx$, scalar product of $\sin nx$ and $\sin nx$, scalar product of $\cos nx$ and $\cos nx$, but we never used scalar product of $\cos nx$ and $\sin nx$, then why it was mentioned? what is the meaning?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110624/discussion-between-zkutch-and-andrew).

Comment: We should comments here not in the chat....you wrote "in the way I have quoted" - where is it?... it is on the first paragraph of the attached image, Yes I agree "product of sin and cos - we know that it's scalar product is 0" as the product is an odd function.

Comment: "first paragraph  of the attached image" - you mean this  https://i.stack.imgur.com/tW6hy.jpg ? If yes, then I see in first paragraph only definition of scalar product. What do you indicate?

Comment: Yes, Start reading the first paragraph... "We wish to obtain an expansion of this
function in terms of the functions...." at last part it is written "functions $\cos (nx), n = 0, 1, 2, \cdots$ and $\sin (nx), n = 1, 2, \cdots $ which are known
to be orthogonal with respect to the standard scalar product on $(−\pi, \pi)$"

Comment: this means $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\sin nx \cos mx dx=0$.

Comment: yes, but we don need to use $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\sin nx \cos mx dx=0$, why it is mentioned? That is the question...

Comment: I cannot answer in place of author. May be he wanted to emphasize, that it is orthogonal system. Anyway, everything written is true. No?

Answer (score 1):

In this case $b_n = 2(-1)^{n+1}/n$.  If you don't want to use the standard general results on convergence of Fourier series, you can do it this way.
$g(z) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n z^n$ is the Maclaurin series of $2 \ln(1+z)$ (using the principal branch of the logarithm) and converges to that for $|z| < 1$ because $\ln(1+z)$ is analytic for $|z|<1$.  For $|z|=1$ with $z \ne -1$, the series converges by Dirichlet's test, and by Abel's theorem the sum of the series is $2 \ln(1+z)$ there.  Note that for $-\pi < t < \pi$,
$$ \eqalign{\sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n \sin(nt) &= \text{Im} \sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n e^{int}\cr
 & = \text{Im} \left(2\ln(1+e^{it})\right) \cr &= \frac{1}{i} \ln\left(\frac{1+e^{it}}{1+e^{-it}}\right) = \frac{1}{i} \ln e^{it} = t}$$

Comment: Why $a_n=0$ because of $f$ is an odd function?  as I see $\langle\cos nx | \cos nx \rangle =\pi$.. so what is the differences?

Comment: If $f(x)$ is an odd function, so is $f(x) \cos(nx)$, so $a_n$ is the integral of an odd function from $-\pi$ to $\pi$ and therefore is $0$.